# How to select the all the edges of a loop cut?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

In Maya when you hold shift and double click on the loop cut, it will select whole edges of loot cut making easier to move the whole loop or delete but how do you do it in Blender?

Answer (score 1):

You can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then select an edge of the loop cut. The rest of the loop cut will automatically be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Crtl(CMD) + R while in edit mode. (I think this is what you're asking).

Once you click it will give you an option to slide the cut.